# Should I still support XML response in my Web-Service?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, rest, playframework

I am not posting this question to start arguments of any kind, I just want to know thoughts of experienced developers, I think this question is related to programming and so I am asking this on SO.

I am designing web-services for my new project, which I plan to open source in future, it is now common these days that consumers of almost all API's are using JSON as their De-Facto format, so my question is should I still support XML in my API's?

I will be using Play framework for my webservices and so I would have to explicitly handle JSON and XML format (I mean seperately) and I want to avoid this.

Would it be appropriate to enforce use of JSON for the consumers of my API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to support client platforms that do not have good support for JSON then you should consider supporting XML.

However, client developer preference is not IMHO a valid reason for supporting multiple formats.